# How to set only one table charset to utf8mb4 without change mysql configuration?

Tags: mysql, character-encoding

Because of the emoji character, I need to change one of my tables to "utf8mb4" charset.
After some google, all of the docs almost have the same steps:

1.Change mysql configuration in the config file, typically, /etc/my.cnf:

```
[mysql]
default-character-set=utf8mb4
......
[mysqld]
character_set_server=utf8mb4
......
```

Then restart mysql.

2.Change the database/table/column charset to utf8mb4, for example:

```
ALTER TABLE test_vstore_message_detail CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin;
```

or,

```
ALTER TABLE test_vstore_message_detail MODIFY `content` TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
ALTER TABLE test_vstore_message_detail CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

My question is, is it possible to ignore step 1, only apply step 2 to make the changes take effect? I only need to change the charset of one table, not of all the tables.

**Currently the charset in mysql configuration is utf8, and we have no chance to restart the server in production. I have tried only step 2 but it didn't work.**

Comment: Yes, step 2 just amends the table's charset and collation. However, in this day and age, utf8mb4 really *should* be the default charset in use (only falling back to something more restrictive when you absolutely require it).

Comment: Thanks. Is utf8mb4 fully backward compatible with utf8? if so, I'll consider to change the global configuration to utf8mb4 and restart server.

Comment: utf8mb4 was added because of a bug in MySQL's utf8 character set. MySQL's handling of the utf8 character set only allows a maximum of 3 bytes for a single codepoint, which isn't enough to represent the entirety of Unicode (Maximum codepoint = 0x10FFFF). Because they didn't want to potentially break any stuff that relied on this buggy behaviour, utf8mb4 was added. [Documentation here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-unicode-utf8mb4.html).

Comment: The OP failed to point out that the table was already `utf8`.  If it had been `latin1`, there would have been more issues.